# Creating package-level associative array in java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, associative-array

Is it possible to create a java representation of a package-level oracle associative array. For example, given the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MyPackage AS
    TYPE t_numbers IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
```

I find I cannot write the following java:

```
ArrayDescriptor descriptor =
    ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("MyPackage.t_numbers", connection);
```

(throws a SQLException "Invalid name pattern").

What is the correct syntax for an ArrayDescriptor referencing a package-level associative array? Does such a thing even exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3696816290928 and especially http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/oci_func.htm#1017512 .

Comment: Second link was spot on, thanks. To summarize - don't use ArrayDescriptor when referencing package-level associative arrays. Cast the callable statement to an OracleCallableStatement and use setPlsqlIndexTable. Doesn't support records, though...

Comment: @Andy many thanks for your comment. It helped me solve the same issue you had, even with link rot affecting the answer's second link.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [OracleConnection.createOracleArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#createOracleArray_java_lang_String__java_lang_Object_)

Note that `arrayTypeName` should be the `table of` type.

Also, you may find my [my answer on getArray() and writeArray()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45867910/197733) useful.